# Centered look for Main Content in tokyo Layout

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, css, page-layout

How can I make the Main Content area centered in the `tokyo` layout?

I tried creating a custom CSS file, adding `.fullPageLayout{width:100%;}` to it, but this class gets overridden by `tokyo.css`  which has the following:

```
.fullPageLayout,.ms-blog-MainArea
{
    width:100%;
    max-width:74em;
}
```

If I try to comment the `74em` part I get a warning that this will break the link with Site definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display:block` is what I needed.

```
.fullPageLayout{margin:0 auto; width:70%; display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it important as

```
.fullPageLayout,.ms-blog-MainArea
{
    width:100% !important;
    max-width:74em !important;
}
```

Best practice is to load you custom css after `corev15.css`

Comment: Tried `!important` but nothing changed. Do you know the path of `corev15.css`?

Comment: `After="Themable/corev15.css"`

Comment: There is no `corev15.css` in my `Themable` folder. Anyway, tried it and nothing changed.